# Expanding commands to build an href from variables passed in

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, hyperref, citing, expansion

I routinely have a large collections (thousands) of pdf documents and a `bash` script that compiles them into a `bib` file based upon the file naming system. In this process the script previously generated a static `\href` to the document in `howpublished` that went into a footnote citation. The static `\href` always opened the linked document (which may be 100's of pages long) at page 1, yet there may be tens of references into any single document, each to a different page, so a reader has to hunt.

The previous static (working) links created by the script were of the form

```
howpublished={\href{run:./biblio/161229.bcw.bmg.mom.0001.Bundle.11.footnotes.ocr.pdf}{[link]}}
```

To eliminate the need for a reader to hunt, I am trying to pass a page number to each footnote along with the `bib` index so that an `\href` can be composed to open any document at any page.

For any document, the path and filename are static and easily pulled from the `bib` file but when I try to compose an `\href` these "inner" commands are not expanded and `\href` breaks.

Is there a way to compose an `\href` using sub-commands in a way similar to the commented out line in the MWE below?

```
% TeXstudio 3.1.2 (git n/a)
% Using Qt Version 5.15.2, compiled with Qt 5.15.2 R

\documentclass[oneside,a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{bib.bib}


% usage \hdetail{bibkey}{page}{commentary text}
\newcommand{\hdetail}[3]{
    \footnote{\cite[Appendix A-\thesection][]{#1} 
        \citeauthor{#1}'s \citefield{#1}{note} of \citedate{#1},  #3
% I want this ....
        \citefield{#1}{howpublished}\#page=#2
% question edited to change ?page to #page 
% to expand inside this .....
%       \href{\citefield{#1}{howpublished}#page=#2}{Link}
    }
}


\begin{document}
    \section{A Section}
    An item.\hdetail{161206.bmg.bcw.eml.1029}{1}{Something to say about it}
\end{document}
```

`bib.bib` currently looks like this

```
@misc{161206.bmg.bcw.eml.1029,author={{Big mak}},note="Email 1029",title={161206.bmg.bcw.eml.1029.Bundle.10.footnotes.ocr.pdf},date="2016-12-06",howpublished={./biblio/161206.bmg.bcw.eml.1029.Bundle.10.footnotes.ocr.pdf}}
@misc{161227.bmg.bcw.let.0002,author={{Big mak}},note="Letter 0002",title={161227.bmg.bcw.let.0002.Bundle.30.footnotes.ocr.pdf},date="2016-12-27",howpublished={./biblio/161227.bmg.bcw.let.0002.Bundle.30.footnotes.ocr.pdf}}
@misc{161229.bcw.bmg.mom.0001,author={{Big cojones}},note="Minutes of meeting 0001",title={161229.bcw.bmg.mom.0001.Bundle.11.footnotes.ocr.pdf},date="2016-12-29",howpublished={./biblio/161229.bcw.bmg.mom.0001.Bundle.11.footnotes.ocr.pdf}}
```

**Corollary**
While the accepted answer was 100% correct in achieving the expansion, `\href` would not successfully parse and compile the `#` in the external anchor. Using `\url` rather than `\href` does parse the `#` so the stopgap solution is

```
\newcommand*{\mypage}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat{howpublished:page}{\tiny\url{#1\#page=\mypage}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`biblatex`'s data printing commands are not expandable, so it is usually safer to have all the processing happen 'inside `biblatex`' via field formats and the like.

Here an added difficulty is that we want to combine `.bib` data with an argument from a macro. A quick way to combine the two is to save the argument in a macro and use that in the field format later. Luckily `\href` is quite forgiving in what it accepts as argument so that works.

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand*{\mypage}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat{howpublished:page}{\href{#1\#page=\mypage}{Link}}

\newcommand{\hdetail}[3]{%
    \footnote{\cite[Appendix A-\thesection][]{#1} 
        \citeauthor{#1}'s \citefield{#1}{note} of \citedate{#1},  #3
        \def\mypage{#2}%
        \citefield{#1}[howpublished:page]{howpublished}%
    }%
}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{161206.bmg.bcw.eml.1029,
  author       = {{Big mak}},
  note         = "Email 1029",
  title        = {161206.bmg.bcw.eml.1029.Bundle.10.footnotes.ocr.pdf},
  date         = "2016-12-06",
  howpublished = {./biblio/161206.bmg.bcw.eml.1029.Bundle.10.footnotes.ocr.pdf},
}
@misc{161227.bmg.bcw.let.0002,
  author       = {{Big mak}},
  note         = "Letter 0002",
  title        = {161227.bmg.bcw.let.0002.Bundle.30.footnotes.ocr.pdf},
  date         = "2016-12-27",
  howpublished = {./biblio/161227.bmg.bcw.let.0002.Bundle.30.footnotes.ocr.pdf},
}
@misc{161229.bcw.bmg.mom.0001,
  author       = {{Big cojones}},
  note         = "Minutes of meeting 0001",
  title        = {161229.bcw.bmg.mom.0001.Bundle.11.footnotes.ocr.pdf},
  date         = "2016-12-29",
  howpublished = {./biblio/161229.bcw.bmg.mom.0001.Bundle.11.footnotes.ocr.pdf},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
    \section{A Section}
    An item.\hdetail{161206.bmg.bcw.eml.1029}{1}{Something to say about it}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code is perfect as per my question but I made an error in the url composition. Please check my edit

Comment: Syntactically this appeared to work, but somewhere along the line, using `#` as is required by acrobat, the suffix from `#` onwards appears ti bf stripped from the url and %23 is not interpreted. If you have any suggestions they would be welcome.

Comment: @bu5hman Unfortunately, I don't know enough about PDF and the PDF specification to be able to help. When you look at the uncompressed suffix you can see that the `#` is present in a part of the link, but not in the main part. Maybe that confuses some readers. But this seems to occur no matter if you use `\#` or `#` (if the latter is possible), so I don't think it has to do with the specifics of the code here. I suggest you ask a new question about that.